# Create unique Id in R by combining 2 columns

Tags: r, excel

I am reading in 2 big .TXT files and filtering them based off a certain code. The codes are located in the 16th column of each file.

```
Colleges <- read.table("Colleges.txt", sep ="|", fill = TRUE)
Majors <- read.table("Majors.txt", sep ="|", fill = TRUE)
```

The Data looks like this

```
bld_name   dpt_name   majors      admin  code  college year
MLK        English    Literature  Ms. W   T    A&S      18
Freedom    Math       Stats       Ms. B   R    STEM      18
MLK       Math        CALC        Ms. B    P    STEM      18
```

After I create the subset and append the two files. I want to create a unique ID using bld_name and dpt_name.

```
college_sub <- subset(colleges,colleges[[16]] %in% c("T", "R"), drop = TRUE) 
    majors_sub <- subset(majors,majors[[16]] %in% c("T", "R"), drop = TRUE)

    combine <- do.call(rbind,list(college_sub,majors_sub)) #Append both files

uniqueID$id <- paste(combine$dpt_name,"-",combine$bld_name)
        cols_g  <- c("dpt_name", "Majors", "Admin", "Year")
        combine <- combine[,cols_g]
```

It should look like this:

```
Unique ID   majors      admin   code  college  year
MLK-English Literature  Ms. W    T    A&S      18
```

Comment: Looks like a job for `dplyr`'s `mutate`, which is most folks' go-to method of making new columns in a data frame.  Something like `mutate(data, Unique_ID = paste(dpt_name, majors, sep = "-"))`

Comment: you could also use `tidyr` 's `unite`

Comment: Can't you just do `combine$id <- paste(combine$dpt_name, combine$bld_name, sep="-")`? (I don't see what would require `mutate` or `unite`; it seems overkill to bring those in just to create this column.)